Can we have multiple web hosts in one ASP.NET Core app with same name and ip?
We are considering to better isolate our application modules (Blazor, Web API, soap) which are currently running on a single DI container provided by AutoFac.
AutoFac documentation has pushed us into the scenario of having multiple hosts in the same app:
var blazorWebHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(X)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>...) // ideally in base path 'webui'

var apiWebHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(Y)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>...) // ideally in base path 'api'

The obvious problem is that with this setup, we can only run one of them, otherwise we are getting port conflicts.
Is it possible to configure the web hosts in such a way that they listen on the same name and port?
I am aware about alternatives, but for the value we want to achieve, they come with quite some overhead...

we could indeed assign multiple ports
we could configure some reverse proxy

Those are not appealing at the moment, due to implications on firewalls, deployment, configuration management which get way less trivial than now.

I suggest you could consider using the YARP to achieve your requirement, put a forent-end application with the YARP and forward the request to each web app according to the url, like www.xxx.com/webapi redirect to the web api project and www.xxx.com/blazor rewrite to the blazor app inside the server. More details, you could refer to this article.
